# How to implement retry strategy in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (OCI) using CLI tool?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-cloud-functions

I am interacting with Oracle Cloud (OCI) using OCI CLI (Command Line Interface), but I dont know how to implement a retry strategy for making api calls.
I know how to build a custom retry strategy using oci sdk for python. I am attaching the command reference for oci cli [oci cli reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/oci-cli/3.4.1/oci_cli_docs/) Please help

Comment: "I am attaching the command..." please try to include the command in your question directly rather than providing a link. This helps in proper readability.

Comment: Hi @sanip I have asked the above question because I couldn't find any command in oci cli reference using which I can implement retry strategy and I need help with finding the retry strategy command in oci cli

Comment: CLI internally calls SDK that handles the retry strategy. What exact CLI command are you trying to use? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @urawesome No I am not getting any error, I want to use CLI commands with custom retry strategy. Can I do that?

Comment: @ashishpm why do you want to use a custom retry strategy? what is the use case?

Comment: @urawesome I have a user configured in OCI, when I try to use the oci cli command 'oci search resource structured-search' I am getting throttling issue probably bcoz this oci user is used simultaneously by multiple clients. So I wanted to use a custom retry strategy and set the sleep parameter accordingly

Comment: Currently OCI CLI doesn't support custom retry. 

Have you tried SDK using DEFAULT_RETRY_STRATEGY vs Custom retry strategy? does default retry strategy in sdk is causing throttling issue? Can you confirm? 

https://oracle-cloud-infrastructure-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sdk_behaviors/retries.html

Comment: @urawesome, in OCI CLI if we don't use the --no-retry argument then by default internally the code makes sdk commands with default retry strategy, so yes throttling issue happens with DEFAULT_RETRY_STRATEGY. Using sdk custom strategy when I increase the base sleep value then the problem is solved